# How to use Saml2ArtifactBinding and retrieve user claims

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm integrating my C# project with an IDP via SAML 2. I have some examples of how to create the login assertion using Saml2PostBinding, but I was not able to find any example about how to do it with Saml2ArtifactBinding.

What is happening now:

1. User requests my C# application login route
2. User is redirected to IDP Login page
3. User logs in
4. IDP redirects the user to my C# application with a query parameter SAMLart

I don't know what to do with this parameter to obtain the user claims.

These are the specifications of my project:

- .NET 7
- ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 v4.8.3.6

Answer (score -1):

First, please use the new version 4.8.3-beta8 (4.8.3.8), it will be released soon.

I think you can find what you need in the artifact [relying party (RP) sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCoreArtifact) and [identity provider (IdP) sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestIdPCore).